# How to find a unique (non-repeated) value in a matrix by using matlab

Tags: matlab, unique

everyone. Let's say I have following (3x3)matrix A:

```
0 1 3
0 0 3
0 0 0
```

My question is how to find out the unique value in that matrix by using matlab? 
In this case, the result should be 1.
I have tried used the

```
value=unique(A)
```

but it returned a vector {0;1;3} is not what I want.

I much appreciate if you guys can help me solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short one

```
value = A(sum(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), A(:).'))==1);
```

It compares all pairs of elements in the matrix and counts how many times they are equal and returns the ones that have been counted only once.

Comment: That's a nice one.  I'm always amazed at how much of my old code is simplified with `bsxfun`.  The MathWorks should have introduced it much earlier.
@* - Just note that there is a temporary square matrix of size `numel(A)*numel(A)` in this solution that could get prohibitive if the matrix size pushes 100+ elements square.  It helps that it is a logical matrix, but it is still good to be aware of this... Recently I posted a slick `bsxfun`-based solution that ended up being unworkable when it turned out the author had a big data set. Of course, this 3x3 example is no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one line alternative:

```
find(histc(A(:), 0:3)==1) - 1
```

or more generally:

```
find(histc(A(:), min(A(:)):max(A(:)))==1) + min(A(:)) - 1
```

OR to generalize it even further (to handle floats)

```
p = 0.1; %//Set a precision.
(find(histc(A(:), min(A(:)):p:max(A(:)))==1) + min(A(:)) - 1)*p
```

Comment: This only works if the elements of the matrix are integers, try it by replacing one of the zero values in the example with `-1.5` or `2.5`.

Comment: Second matlab line works best when the matrix is of generous size. My case is 1e6 elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The method of counting I generally prefer uses `sort` and `diff` as follows,

```
[x,sortinds] = sort(A(:));
dx = diff(x);
thecount = diff(find([1; dx; 1]));
uniqueinds = [find(dx); numel(x)];
countwhat = x(uniqueinds);
```

Then you grab the value(s) with only one occurrence:

```
lonelyValues = countwhat(thecount==1)
```

If you want the location of these value(s) in the matrix:

```
valueInds = sortinds(uniqueinds(thecount==1))
[valRows,valCols] = ind2sub(size(A),valueInds)
```

If you expect to any `NaN` and/or `Inf` values in your matrix, you have to do additional bookkeeping, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative using `unique()` and `hist()`:

count elements:

```
[elements,indices,~] = unique(A);              % get each value with index once
counts = hist(A(:), elements);                 % count occurrences of elements within a
```

get elements:

```
uniqueElements = elements(counts==1);          % find unique elements
```

get indices:

```
uniqueIndices  =  indices(counts==1);          % find unique indices
[uRow, uCol] = ind2sub(size(A),uniqueIndices); % get row/column representation
```