# Find node index of connected graph components using conncomp

Tags: matlab, graph

**Problem**

I am trying to find the connected components of my undirected graph.
Matlabs function `conncomp` does exactly this. [Mathworks - connected graph components](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.conncomp.html)

**Example**

Using the example given on matlabs webpage to keep it easy and repeatable:

```
G = graph([1 1 4],[2 3 5],[1 1 1],6);
plot(G)
```

[image: Graph]

```
 bins = conncomp(G)
    bins =
     1     1     1     2     2     3
```

**Two Question´s to this**

*First Question:* Using this how can I find the initial node index, so that

```
     cluster1 = (1 2 3); (instead of ( 1 1 1))
     cluster2= (4 5);    (instead of (2 2))
```

*Second Question:*

I am working on a big dataset and I know many nodes are not connected, so is there a way to only display clusters that contain more than one value ?
Thanks for your help, I am majorly stuck here.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236914/how-to-find-a-unique-non-repeated-value-in-a-matrix-by-using-matlab) is a possible duplicate but I'm hesitant to mark it as such because with large data sets [histcounts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) is likely better than the `bsxfun` approach and is now preferred over `histc`.

Comment: Wouldnt that only correspond to the second part of the question ? My main question is rather how to find the nodes that are displayed by the bins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the first part of the question can be answered very simply as Matlabs `conncomp` provides a tool for this:

```
bins=conncomp(G,'OutputForm','cell');
```

Creates a cell array that contains the clusters, with all node names in the cells.
For the second part of the question I guess there are several ways but this one could be used as well:

```
clusters= bins(cellfun(@numel,bins)>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`splitapply`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) for the first part, like so:

```
clusters = splitapply(@(x) {x}, 1:numnodes(G), bins)
```

This returns a `cell` array where each cell contains the indices of the nodes in a group. You can filter this down in the usual way using `cellfun`

```
discard = cellfun(@isscalar, clusters);
clusters(discard) = [];
```

(Note that `splitapply` is new in R2015b - but the OP is using `graph`, also new in R2015b, so it should be fine for them)

Comment: I found a way as well, i posted it in the answer below, what do you think about that ? Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Ah, your way is much better - I should have read the doc for `conncomp`!

Comment: If I would have read it properly I would have needed to ask the question ;) :D but thanks anyway :)